# How to get the output of a script running on remote machine via gsclient?

Tags: python, batch-file, telnet, openedge, progress-4gl

I have two machines, connected via telnet, PC1 and PC2.

I'm running on PC1 a progress-4gl script stored on PC1 via a GSclient from PC2.

That script runs a batch script which launches a python script to run on PC2.

That python script runs as intended, and then returns an output which is needed for the rest of the code in the progress script on PC1, the so-called "parent script" I guess.

How can I return that output from the python script on PC2, to the batch script on PC1, and back to the "parent script" on PC1?

Currently, I'm using OUTPUT THROUGH on the "parent", to run the batch.
On the batch I'm using GS_exec.exe to run the python script on PC2.

progress.p:

```
def var script_to_run as c.
script_to_run = "path/to/script/to/run/on/PC2/script.py".
output through value("path/to/exe_python.bat " + script_to_run ).
```

exe_python.bat:

```
@echo off
set INFILE=%~f1
C:\GS_UTS\GS_Exec.exe "python %INFILE%"
```

script.py:

```
codecodecode...
return output
```

Expected result would be:
progress code runs on PC1> batch runs on PC1> python code runs on PC2> output from python code returned to batch on PC1> returned to original progress code.

Actual result is:
progress code runs on PC1> batch runs on PC1> python code runs on PC2> output isn't returned anywhere, and the original code just runs without the wanted output after the completion of the python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the output from the Python returned to Progress you use INPUT THROUGH in your Progress code.  (Progress' INPUT is the output from your Python code.)

```
define variable script_to_run as character no-undo.
define variable result as character no-undo.

script_to_run = "path/to/script/to/run/on/PC2/script.py".

INPUT THROUGH value( "path/to/exe_python.bat " + script_to_run ).

import unformatted result.
display result.
```

Comment: The input through method does make the Progress code wait for a returned value, but the problem is it takes the first line of output, and as my Python script runs a chromedriver, it firstly prints the chromedriver's terminal initiation lines, and eventually the actual wanted output. Is there a way to run a chromedriver without it printing those terminal lines, or using the last output line via INPUT THROUGH maybe?

Comment: I found this: options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']) to disable the terminal print from chromedriver, and now it works as intended.

Comment: You can also put the IMPORT statement inside a REPEAT loop if you need to process multiple lines of data.